# Absolute positioning with percentages giving unexpected results

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

Please consider this HTML and CSS snippet:

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#item {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">TEST</div>
</div>
```

The results surprise me. Looking at the [W3 positioning props](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) I'd expect the `#item` to have its left value at 50% of the "containing block": the `#container`. However, it seems to be at 50% of the entire page, not just the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block). Even more surprising: if I tell the overflow of the container to stay hidden the "TEST" will still be there.

All major browsers (including IE9) seem to exhibit the same behavior, so my expectations are probably incorrect. ***The question then is***: *what part of the spec explains this behavior, if any?*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The absolute positioning is applied relative to the next parent element whose position is not static. In your case, that's the full page. Try setting `position: relative` on the container division.
[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YkAPn/4/)

**See:** [W3C - 10.1 - Definition of "containing block"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

Answer (score 3):

add

```
position:relative;
```

to container div .

Answer (score -3):

When giving an element absolute position you take it out of the normal flow of the document. Absolute is the very upper left portion of the screen regardless of the other elements in the page. So by saying left: 50% you're saying half way in from the absolute left of the screen.

Comment: That is `position: fixed`, which always uses the full page container. Absolute positioning does apply to its parent elements, see my answer.

Comment: Too true. I fully agree. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, but if there are no ancestors relatively positioned, the answer is at least partially correct with an extra point because the other answers don't really reply to the question. Absolute position can be used with static ancestors. Its behaviour is a similar with fixed, the difference is that when you scroll down and up the page, the absolute positioned element with static ancestors goes along with the page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13239575/4551792