# absolute positioning with percentages 50%

Tags: css

I found an anwswer from this:
[Absolute positioning with percentages giving unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404603/absolute-positioning-with-percentages-giving-unexpected-results)

but the answer is not quite right shows on my screen

Here is **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YkAPn/4/)** from that answer.

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#item {
    border: 1px dashed purple;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

[image]

I am having this issue, 50% is not half of the parent's width, if someone could help?

Comment: 50% is half of the parent's width. If you look at the space between the left red border and the letter `T`, that is half of the parent's width.

Comment: What do you expect it to display?

Comment: display to the center of the parent's width

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 yes!! thanks. I got it now.

Comment: See my answer which centers the TEST without using absolute positioning and negative valued styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correctly positioning the element at 50% - the top left corner of the `item` element is at this point.  If you want to completely center it absolutely, you need to add a negative left margin of half the `item` width:

```
#item {
    border: 1px dashed purple;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

If this isn't going to suit your needs, look into using `text-align: center` and `margin: 0 auto` as an option instead.  In your jsFiddle, it's not exactly clear what the end goal is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where is `-20px` from?

Comment: Your `item` element is 41px wide, so half of that is ~20px.  Adding a negative left margin pulls the item 20px to the left, making it centered.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the x and y pixel position, the item div is positioned at 50% of the width of your container div (ie. 50px from the left of a 100px container).

If you increase the width of your container you will see the item div positions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style. There is no need for absolute and negative valued styles:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#item {
    border: 1px dashed purple;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YkAPn/205/)

Comment: Thanks but I need absolute and its parent relative for images sometime